# pipenv installation issue in Windows 10

Tags: pipenv, pipenv-install

[click to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfbdW.png)
I am trying to install pipenv in my windows 10 for my PyCharm. As you can see, the requirements are all fulfilled. But there is an error. WARNING: Failed to write executable - trying to use .deleteme logic
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe' -> 'C:\Python39\Scripts\pipenv.exe.deleteme'

Yet, there is no message as succesfully installed pipenv. I also checked my folders. There is no sign of pipenv.exe under Scripts
[click to see the requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoANb.png)

Comment: just search online for `trying to use .deleteme logic` and go through the threads you find. Seems to be a permission issue, did you perhaps install python as admin? that's not optimal